# Order by not working in WordPress post loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I want my products to order by specific items but when I add the order query the products are not longer showing on the page.

Here is the query I am using:

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=ASC');?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); global $product; ?>
<div class="col-md-4 mt-5 mb-5">
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" class="d-block w-100">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" class="img-fluid head-image d-block mx-auto">
            <?php if( $product->is_on_sale() ) { ?>
            <div class="image-content">
                <div class="sale">
                    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/part', 'sale'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
```

When I remove the first line `<?php query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=ASC');?>` the products are showing but not ordering.

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: What does `$query_string` contain? And _where_ are you trying to do this whole thing here to begin with? Have you read what the documentation for `query_posts` has to say? _“Note: This function will completely override the main query and isn’t intended for use by plugins or themes. Its overly-simplistic approach to modifying the main query can be problematic and should be avoided wherever possible.”_

Answer (score 0):

There is a great article on wp_query vs query_posts over on stackexchange (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Perhaps you could consider

```
$args = array( /* your args: refer to wp_query() for requirements */
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Sorry I'm on my phone and cant produce better examples. But wp_query is a much more preferred option as stated:

> query_posts() is overly simplistic and a problematic way to modify the main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination). Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods, like making use of the pre_get_posts hook, for this purpose. TL;DR don't use query_posts() ever.
>
> get_posts() is very similar in usage and accepts the same arguments (with some nuances, like different defaults), but returns an array of posts, doesn't modify global variables and is safe to use anywhere.
>
> WP_Query is the class that powers both behind the scenes, but you can also create and work with your own instance of it. A bit more complex, fewer restrictions, also safe to use anywhere.